# Butter cake creaming method

Tags: butter

I am living in Asia and it's summer here for all year long. 
I realised that my butter tends to melts very fast when I am doing creaming method. Will the melted butter affect the texture of my cake?

Comment: Melt completely as in "becomes liquid" or just very, very soft? What's the room temperature in your kitchen?

Comment: It's very, very soft.. I am not sure about the temperature in my kitchen.. but temperature outside my house around 30 degree Celsius and I only have wall fan in the kitchen

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with the same situation - very warm in the kitchen and the butter gets super soft, sometimes with a very slight bit of melting. This has never negatively affected the outcome of my cake.

But, anytime you think it may be too warm in your kitchen, you can put a mixing bowl in the fridge or freezer and let it get cold while the butter softens. Then, when ready to start creaming the butter and sugar together, transfer the butter to the cold bowl. This ensures that the butter will not continue to get warmer during the creaming process.